# Why can't I scroll down for metrics in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I can't find the scrollbar for the column that contains metrics. This is preventing me from scrolling down to see additional metrics. The scrollbar on the left is not for metrics but for the table in the report.

Screenshot of column:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to use an external mouse and the mouse wheel to scroll.
2. If you use a laptop, your touch-pad might support scrolling with two-finger up/down swipe gestures.
3. Switch to the Style tab, scroll down, switch back to the Data tab.

No idea, why they don't separate the scrollbars for the Data and Style panels and make it as one would expect.

If you need a scroll bar anyway, you can install a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne?hl=en) or a [Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/) like Stylus and then:

1. Go to the Google Data Studio website.
2. Open the Stylus options from the Extensions menu.
3. Click on "datastudio.google.com" under "Write style for:" and then a Stylus page would open.
4. Click on Import from the left sidebar and paste the below CSS code into the dialog that opens and select "Overwrite Style".
5. Click on Save or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (Windows or Linux) / <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (macOS).

CSS code:

```css
@-moz-document regexp("https://datastudio.google.com/.*/.*/reporting/.*") {
  form[name="panelForm"] {
     display: flex !important;
     flex-direction: column !important;
  }

  .tab-data {
      height: 100% !important;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto !important;
  }

  property-panel .ga-form::after {
     height: auto !important;
  }
}
```